# Find max unbalanace binary search tre in C

Tags: c

i'm just struggling about how to get the max unbalance value i binary search tree in c code, online i havent found anything.

Basicaly i have a binary search tree which is unbalanced and i have to get the max unbalance value of the whole tree, what i'm missing is how to calculate the max unbalance value in general for each iteration...

if someone can post here a simple code of how he would do it it wuld be very good, just a simple code for a general BST in c with this structure

```
typedef struct _node {
    int key;
    struct _node* left;
    struct _node* right;
} node;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is a "max unbalance value" something different from simply the maximum value stored in the (unbalanced) tree?  I'm uncertain what you mean by the term.

Comment: @JohnBollinger if it is the maximum value the answer is in my code. but now i think that the max unbalance value may be the value of iterations to find the last value in a "path"

Comment: Do you mean the greatest difference between the number of nodes any left and right sub-tree pair?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like recursive approach. Note that in my code example when you will call the function it must be something like this `findMaxValue(treeroot, &int)`

```
 void findMaxValue(struct node* node, int * maxvalue)  {   
    if (node==NULL) {
        return; 
    }
    else {
        if(*maxvalue < node->data){
            *maxvalue = node->data;
        }
        size(node->left, maxvalue);
        size(node->right, maxvalue);
        return;
    }
}
```